# choose the correct option of given function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$A = f(B) \subseteq \mathbb R$ where $B$ is a closed interval contained in $(0, \infty)$ and $f(t)= \log t$.

1. Open
2. closed
3. connected
4. compact

From my point of view $f(t)$ must be closed, by the theorem continuous image of a closed set is closed , closed map  to closed map , but I don't know  whether it is compact or connected . I have no idea any other idea about this compact and connected. I know that a circle and an ellipse are  both compact and connected. Here this is not mentioned, so I'm very confused.

If anbody help me I would be very thankful to him.

Comment: you have to say inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function

Comment: yes, closed  map to closed @ marios gretsas

Answer (score 0):

Ok we have that if $a>0$ then $B=[a, b]$ which is a closed interval.

Also $b$ can be $\infty$.

The image $f(B)$ is not always compact under $f(t)=\log{t}$
Take for instance $B=[1,+ \infty)$ which is  closed.But $f(B)=[0,+ \infty)$  is not compact because from  Heine-Borel theorem  ,a subset of the real line is compact iff is closed and bounded.Thus we cannot choose $4$.It is not always the case.

Now from a theorem in general topology we know that a continuous image of a connected set,is also connected.

Every interval $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$(in the case every subset of $(0, +\infty)$)   is connected thus  $f(B)$ is connected.So $3$ is correct.

Because $f$ is invertible and continuous you can prove that $f(B)$ is closed if $B$ is closed.

But if $B$ is closed then it cannot be open because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected thus from definition of connectedness in a topological space we have that a space is connected if the only clopen(closed and open at the same time) subsets of the space are the space itself and the empty set.

Thus $1$ is not the case.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot @ marios gretsas

Comment: if it helped you you can accepted if you want